# Low performance when adding values to a listobject in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to print a large amount of data to a listobject, and the function I have written works, but is extremely slow:

```
Public Sub PrintCollectionToTableByHeaderName(tb As ListObject, values As Collection, keylist as Collection, Optional rownum As Long, Optional alreadyvalidated As Boolean)
Dim i As Integer
    If TbColsAreValid(tb, keylist, alreadyvalidated) Then
        If Not rownum <> 0 Then: rownum = tb.ListRows.count + 1
        For i = 1 To keylist.count
            tb.ListColumns(keylist(i)).DataBodyRange(rownum, 1).value = values(keylist(i))
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "Err: Headers Not Valid"
    End If
End Sub
```

Would anyone be able to suggest a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is it useful to add a `DoEvents` above the `Next i` line?

Comment: I don't know how these items affect your code but they appear strange to me. 1) `keylist As enter code here'Collection` and 2) `If Not rownum <> 0 Then`. Also, what makes you so sure that your procedure `TbColsAreValid` isn't to blame for the slow progress? Better let us see that code, too.

Comment: @Variatus Sorry, the `keylist` was a mistake in copying the code in, I've edited that now. `If Not rownum <> 0 Then` is for when you are printing the data to a new line, where the `ROWNUM` would not be passed into the function. The `TbColsAreValid` is to validate that all of the entries in `Keylist` exist as the names of listcolumns, the optional `alreadyvalidated` parameter can be passed in to make it skip that step, which is being used where I'm having the issue.

Comment: @MuzafferGalata Thank you, I have added it, and it has marginally improved the performance, however, it is still far too slow. looping through the first 100 lines takes around 15 seconds when leaving this function in, commenting it out results in the whole process taking less than 1 second.

Comment: If the code works as intended but just performs poorly, consider putting it up (including the `TbColsAreValid` function and a bit of context e.g. the number of items in the `values` collection, the number of listrows in that `ListObject`, what's in the `keyList` collection) for peer review on [codereview.se]. Side note, "if *not* rownum *not*equal zero" is a double negative that should probably read "if rownum equals zero" instead; and the `:` instructions separator following `Then:` is a bit syntactically weird given the one-line `If` condition, should be `If...Then...`, in one instruction =)

Comment: Is the `keyList` collection keyed? If not, consider replacing it with an array: object collections *want* to be iterated (with `For Each` loops) - if it's just a list of strings / column names and you're always accessing it by index, an array will perform orders of magnitude faster. Or, cache a reference to the `DataBodyRange` of each column by keying a `Dictionary` with column names and then retrieving the object with a key lookup. IMO we're going to need more information about exactly what's going on, in order to provide a meaningfully useful performance/code review.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you, though from further testing, it looks like the actual code is fine, I've used the same function in some tests and it's performed perfectly, taking less than 3 seconds to print 26 entries 1000 times. So I guess it's an issue with either the data being used, or the tables themselves, though I have no idea what. Thank you you for trying :)

Comment: @AlxRiash if calculation mode is set to `Automatic`, then a calculation-heavy workbook would take a while to run this loop, because each iteration prompts a recalc. Try setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before looping, and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` after the loop (and in case of any error); worksheet will only recalc once when you set calculation mode back to automatic.

Comment: `If Not rownum <> 0 Then` includes a double negation which is equal to a single affirmation. Therefore the condition is the same as `If rownum = 0 Then`. The colon that follows in your code is superfluous. I don't know if it's harmful. Normally, a colon signifies a new line of code and if what follows were in a new line then `End If` would be required. Maybe your code spends time looking for the `End If` before deciding that it knows how to handle the exception.